# is it possible to copy an action hook in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

Is there any way to duplicate an action in wordpress and edit it ?

I  want to copy the "woocommerce_single_product_summary" hook (with a different name) and then remove / add some action to it so i will have 2 function.

let's say woocommerce_single_product_summary and woocommerce_single_product_summary_2.

Each one should be independant and if i do something like (on function.php) :

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart', 30 );

It will not remove it on woocommerce_single_product_summary_2

Thanks you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing something in your question. By duplicating a hook, you are trying to make some changes to an existing function. You can do that by removing the old function and adding a new function to the hook.

If you are looking to attach another function to the same hook say, `woocommerce_single_product_summary` you can use add_action to attach a function to the hook.

If you want to remove the function from hook without removing your function, then you have the option,

```
remove_action( $tag, $function_to_remove, $priority );
```

This will only remove the function which is specified in the `$function_to_remove` position